# Remove connection between VSC Project and Github

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have created a project in VSC and then decided to upload it to my github. I connected VSC with Git and created a repository through VSC. The upload failed so I deleted the repository on Github, but for some reason the project is still connected to github (The letters A,U,M next to the file names) How do I unlink this connection so that my project is again an offline project?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute in the Visual Studio console the following command

> git remote rm

And then restart vscode, it will be disconnected from the git repository

Comment: This is not working. It asks for the name of the repository, but that does not exist since I manually deleted it